# Facebook login stuck

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Facebook login into my app and I'm closely following the documentation.

1. I set up the `Info.plist` file
2. I also set up the `AppDelegate`

In the `viewDidLoad` method I have the folling code:

```
let loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
loginButton.center = view.center
loginButton.delegate = self
view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

The viewController conforms to the delegate:

```
extension FacebookLoginViewController: LoginButtonDelegate {
        func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {
            switch result {
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login")
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Failed: \(error)")
            case .success:
                print("Successful login")
            }
        }

        func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: LoginButton) { print("Logged out") }
}
```

When I click the login button an in-app browser window comes up and it asks whether I want to login with the Facebook app or the browser. 
[screenshot of selection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSqVB.png)

If I **select the browser** then I need to enter my username and password and **it works**.

If I **select the app** and go through the authentication process and come back to my app **it is like nothing happened**. The prompt to select the Facebook app or the browser is still there. And the request didn't fail or succeed or anything. It doesn't even call the delegate method.

Is there something else I need to do for the Authentication to work through the app?

Comment: To get notifications of login results or logout events assign a delegate to LoginButton that confirms to the LoginButtonDelegate.

Comment: @aBilal17 I added the delegate and updated the question accordingly. However the delegate doesn't get called at all. But even before I added the delegate the results were printed out in the console.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, had you find any solution?

Comment: @ShreeshGarg Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. **Straight from Facebook iOS team:** All you need to do is to add this function in your AppDelegate file.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```